# replace draggable element with another in droppable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I try to replace an draggable element with another draggable element in an droppable element. If for example drag1 is in div1 and drag2 becomes dragged into div1, drag1 should run to the div where drag2 comes from and drag1 is now in div1. In my demo becomes drag2 rejected. How can I realize that?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zeXuM/430/)

```
  function handleDropEvent (event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.element !== undefined) {
        ui.draggable.element.droppable('enable');
    }
    $(this).droppable('disable');
    ui.draggable.position({of: $(this),my: 'left top',at: 'left top'});
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', "invalid");
    ui.draggable.element = $(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8gosy0h/2/)

This example is three divs, two that fights for the `drag-goal`.
Basically `handleConflict(jQueryElement)` checks to see if the element is right above the target div - if it is - and the element hasnt been set as targeted -it assumes it as "set" and continues. Now, if the occupyingelement has been set (i,e is "over it") - then it will force the old element to take its old place.

var occupyingSpace = "null";

```
function handleConflicts(element){

    console.log($("#drag-goal").position());
    console.log(element.position());

    if(element.position().top == $("#drag-goal").position().top && 
                element.position().left == $("#drag-goal").position().left && occupyingSpace == "null"){
       occupyingSpace = element;
       console.log("defined occupyingSpace as this element")
    }
    else if(element.position().top == $("#drag-goal").position().top && 
                element.position().left == $("#drag-goal").position().left && occupyingSpace != "null"){
       occupyingSpace.css({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
       })
       occupyingSpace = element;
       console.log("is taken");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but there are divs that are overlapping and not replacing.